# Get Airflow Dag Concurrent Runs in MWAA

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

Can we get the airflow dag run count( concurrency) , which runs in MWAA? I set the concurrency on Dag Level. But I would like to get dag concurrency, and if it is below a specific limit would like to trigger the dag.

Since the dag is running in MWAA , is there a metric available to get this count ? I found `PoolRunningSlots` metric  which is very close to get Concurrent Dag run count( *checked couple of times, this value is same as the run count of the dag* ).
FYI, PoolRunningSlots
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/access-metrics-cw-202.html#access-metrics-cw-console-v202

Please let me know if you encounter this before. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you want to do it manually, because Airflow can do it by just configuring `max_active_runs` (use your specific limit) which defines how many running concurrent instances of a DAG there are allowed to be.

For `PoolRunningSlots` metric, it's the number of slots used for a specific pool, so if you have a pool used in different dags, or different pools used in your dag (a different pool for each task), or the tasks used different number of slots (check the [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/pools.html#using-multiple-pool-slots)), in these cases `PoolRunningSlots` will be very different from the concurrent Dag runs count.

If you really need this metric, you can create a custom metric by adding a task at the beginning of your dag which increment a cloud watch metric ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-custom-metrics.html)), and adding `on_success_callback` and `on_failure_callback` to your dag to decrease the same metric, in this case this new metric will represent the count of the active runs of your dag.